# How to verify whether my app is installed or not in other user's device in android?

Tags: android

Iam doing Quiz application.In this application I would like to challenge a question to the users.For this, First of all I should verify whether my app is installed or not in other user's device whom i challenging the question.If app is installed I have to send a particular screen from my app.If app is not installed in user's device just send the playstore link.

Is my requirement is possible to implement in android?

Comment: first think how to connect to other (new) device ?

Comment: can u please give me brief idea on this?? @suhas

Comment: I think you are not in the right path. I mean, how are you going to connect to the other device? How are you going to send the play store link? You cannot perform the action you want into a remote device.

Comment: My thought is first of all I have to retrieve the mobile number internally whom i challenge the question and compare that mobile number with database.If that mobile number is already exist in database we can confirm that user already installed the app..But Iam not getting how to retrieve that particular mobile number...
Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Since There is no way to connect to the other user's phone, this is not possible. But I would like to propose you a alternative way to implement this application.

It should like this,

Initially both users should have the application installed in their devices. Application users can see the `online users` who already installed the app. Primary user can send a challenge to the online users by selecting one or more users from the `online users list`. Then the user/users who received the challenge should `Accept the challenge` in-order to join to the challenge.

You should have knowledge about `Google cloud Messaging`, `Web services` to implement this.

Or Else

You can build a separate UI to invite for other people who don't have app installed by sending A email with google play store url of your app. When the other user click this link, Google Play app will automatically start with your app download location

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. But in practice, android devs just send the Play Store link anyways, because if a user who has the app installed clicks on that link, he only has to press the open button in the Play Store. So you see, it's not much of a difference if you open the app or the Play Store Page. Your text could look like

> *username* challenged you to play *appname*! Can you beat his score? *link*